# xargs echo `echo {} | sed 's/pattern/replace/'` doesn't work but for each loop works

Tags: linux, shell, sed, command, xargs

I want to do the equivalent of:

```
for i in `ls -1`; do echo $i | mv $i `sed 's/profile/account/'`; done
```

with `xargs`

```
ls -1 | xargs -I{} mv {} `echo {} | sed 's/profile/account/'`
```

But the `sed` after the pipe within backticks is ignored.
Anyone know why that's the case?

### Edit: More info

The root problem is simply to rename files in a directly given a pattern replacement (here replace `profile` with `account`, however that is solved with `for in` loop over the files.

#### The question I'm posing is why is the following not working.

```
ls -1 | xargs -I{} mv {} `echo {} | sed 's/profile/account/'`
```

Why does the

```
`echo {} | sed 's/profile/account/'`
```

portion not return the replaced filename but the original filename. It's as if the `|` doesn't work inside the backticks.

#### To write the problem differently:

If I have a list like in a file called `list.txt`

```
profile1.txt
profile2.txt
```

And want to generate

```
account1.txt
account2.txt
```

While operating on each individual line separately so I can run a command on it.

```
cat list.txt | xargs -I{} echo `echo {} | sed 's/profile/account/'`
```

Why does command return:

```
profile1.txt
profile2.txt
```

Instead of changing profile to account?

Comment: Wrong quotes around `echo {} ...`?

Comment: first of all, please [don't parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).. use `for i in *`.. second, [put variables inside double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) unless you have some other reason... finally, could you explain what is the problem you are trying to solve? ideally, give us one or two filenames and what is your expected output for those

Comment: you could use [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) directly on shell variables instead of calling `sed` (unless you need regex features)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example:

```
cat list.txt | xargs -I{} echo `echo {} | sed 's/profile/account/'`
```

xargs does not interpolate the `{}` inside of backticks.

So:

```
`echo {} | sed 's/profile/account/'`
```

Echos the literal `{}`. The subsequent `sed` does not change the `{}`.

```
`echo {} | sed 's/profile/account/'`
```

Will return: `{}`

Which gives:

```
cat list.txt | xargs -I{} echo {}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel 'old={}; new=${old/profile/account}; echo mv $old $new' ::: *
```

Remove `echo` once checked.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the comments above regarding using shell glob expansion rather than `ls -1`, or the straightforward solution using `prename`, nevertheless the exercise is interesting also in case you wanted to feed the pipe other outputs (e.g. `find` or alike).

Below does it via calling a mini scriptlet where its argument is each `xargs` fed line, using var replacement bash-isms (note the narrowed `ls ...` to be able to re-run these without errors):

```
ls -1 *profile* | xargs -l1 bash -xc 'echo mv "$1" "${1/profile/account}"' --
```

Note above is a *dry-run*, remove the `echo` to actually do it.